# Accidentally aborted 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade while checking a changed config file

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, crash

I looked at various answers to similar questions.  One of them said to reboot and run:

dpkg --config -a

So I attempted to reboot but it's not rebooting.

I get the grub menu and have chosen advanced options and chosen older versions of Linux images but to no avail.

Whilst booting it tells me that wifi networks are available and I should choose. But no way to do that.

Any thoughts, please?

Comment: If you interrupted the upgrade your system is probably unrecoverable and you'll need to install from installation media.

Comment: Thanks @Nmath.  It's what I'm dreading.  Any way of installing 20.04 from installation media but still retain most of my data?  Can I try installing 18.04 from installation media and still expect to have the bulk of my configuration and data available?

Comment: I believe you can just install 20.04 on top of your current installation.  It's possible that the new files might overwrite whichever ones were corrupted during the interruption.  You can also back up your home folder. Many of the configs under `~/.` are probably OK

Comment: Yes I was thinking of installing 20.04 directly over....as long as it doesn't clobber my data and mysql configurations...then I'll survive.

Comment: Make sure your backups are in order!

Comment: You haven't said if you're using desktop or server. You can *release-upgrade* a desktop via re-install (using something-else, ensure you don't format) where it notes packages added, erases system directories, installs, adds back additional packages you have (*this function is disappearing but exists on older media*) then asks to reboot. No user file is touched, however as server apps store *conf* files in system directories, they'll get erased (desktop programs all use $HOME directories so are untouched).  Be careful to ensure you don't format & ensure you have backups as easy to make mistake

Comment: @guiverc yes you are right.  I'm sorry, I'm talking about desktop.  Since I was upgrading to 18.04 from 16.04 should I use fresh media to install 18.04 or try to install 16.04?

Comment: The version installed is of course the version you are moving to, the *upgrade* via re-install allows you to skip releases, and actually in my deals with 3rd party software better (*it's left out with an error that some packages could not be re-installed; but this still annoyed people who wrote bugs & the fix to that was to remove the feature thus my disappearing comment*).  I've always considered this option my *backup* procedure should a `do-release-upgrade` have issues  (it's also far quicker so have used it as my first case too if need the machine in a hurry).

Comment: I'd avoid aborting upgrades/installs, if the download has completed & install/upgrade started; I feel it's safer to let it finish & reverse it afterwards. It's usually quicker than fixing the damage caused by forcing an abort (in my opinion, I'll watch the screen & decide my action depending on where it is & what I consider the damage; usually opting to let it go unless sure I can cleanly interrupt/abort).

Comment: @guiverc the abort was accidental.  I was looking at the diff between 2 versions of a config file and I couldn't get out of that by pressing 'q'.  So I tried ctrl+c ....stupidly.  Thanks for your response.  I'll try installing 18.04.

Comment: Ok I managed to get 18.04 loaded and working....but it's like having a completely new build.  NONE of my previous configurations remain.  I will have to rebuild all my Rails and other applications from scratch.  This isn't what I was expecting.  I am at a TOTAL LOSS as to how BAD an upgrade can go.  No warning about Ctrl+c NOT to be used. No advice on how to exit a config diff view.